# Adding Javascript code (Embed form code) to Mediawiki page

Tags: mediawiki, hubspot

I want to add a hubspot form using its embed code(Javascript) to a mediaWiki page. Will i be able to do this? if so How?

I could not find a proper solution or answer anywhere.

Comment: Try adding the code to the page `MediaWiki:Common.js`.

Comment: I figured it out - Had to enable $wgRawHtml = true; and had to use the code inside <HTML> tags. Since my mediawiki is limited to only authorised admin users enabling $wgRawHtml = true; did not matter. Enabling $wgRawHtml = true on a open login site with edit permissions to everyone would be a huge security issue.

Comment: Add to MediaWiki:Common.js adds the code sitewide

Comment: You can check the current page: `if mw.config.get('wgPageName') === 'title')...`.

Comment: if you have access to MediaWiki configuration, you can use the hook `BeforePageDisplay` in `LocalSettings.php` or in a speciall made extension (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/BeforePageDisplay):
```
    $wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = function ( OutputPage $out, Skin $skin ): bool {
        $out->addScriptFile( '/path/to/your/sctipt.js' );
 return true;
    };
```

Comment: And the condition to add JS to only certain page will be like: `if ( $out->getPageTitle()->getText() === 'Page title' )`.